# Datagrid values shows up in wrong position

Tags: .net, database, vb.net, datagridview, datagrid

I have a datagridview which displays the data from my database. However, whenever I clicked in the datagrid for the first and second time, data shows up in the designated textboxes but after several saving and updating, it will show up in wrong textboxes. The problem showed up after I added the binding source, dataset and datatable for the purpose of filtering the datagrid. I can't find what the problem is because it is not prompting any errors.

This is the code for the datagridview

```
 Private Sub forreviewdatagrid_CellClick(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles forreviewdatagrid.CellClick

    Dim row As DataGridViewRow = forreviewdatagrid.CurrentRow

    Try
        cmbboxcateg.Text = row.Cells(0).Value.ToString()
        DateTimePickerForReview.Text = row.Cells(1).Value.ToString()
        txtbrandname.Text = row.Cells(2).Value.ToString()
        txtprodname.Text = row.Cells(3).Value.ToString()
        txtproddesc.Text = row.Cells(4).Value.ToString()
        txtcolor.Text = row.Cells(5).Value.ToString()
        txtodor.Text = row.Cells(6).Value.ToString()
        txttaste.Text = row.Cells(7).Value.ToString()
        txttexture.Text = row.Cells(8).Value.ToString()
        txtform.Text = row.Cells(9).Value.ToString()
        txtshelflife.Text = row.Cells(10).Value.ToString()
        txtpackmat.Text = row.Cells(11).Value.ToString()
        txtdescofprod.Text = row.Cells(12).Value.ToString()
        txtstoragereq.Text = row.Cells(13).Value.ToString()
        txtdirforuse.Text = row.Cells(14).Value.ToString()
        txtfuncfoodmat.Text = row.Cells(15).Value.ToString()
        txtallergen.Text = row.Cells(16).Value.ToString()
        txtlotcode.Text = row.Cells(17).Value.ToString()
        txtopendate.Text = row.Cells(18).Value.ToString()
        txttypefoodprod.Text = row.Cells(19).Value.ToString()
        txtprodrisk.Text = row.Cells(20).Value.ToString()
        txtprodcateg.Text = row.Cells(21).Value.ToString()

      Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

End Sub
```

This is the code for filtering the datagridview

```
 Private Sub btnSearch_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click

    Dim pistableadapter As New MySqlDataAdapter("Select * From pis, pis2 WHERE productid=productidrev", MysqlConn)

    Dim pistable As New DataTable()

    pistableadapter.Fill(dt)
    pisBindingSource.DataSource = dt
    pisBindingSource.Filter = "prodname = '" & txtsearch.Text & "' "
    forreviewdatagrid.DataSource = pisBindingSource


End Sub
```

Comment: You don't need any code at all. You should be binding all those other controls to the data as well as the grid.

Comment: When I added the binding source, table adapter and dataset into the form, that's when the problem started @jmcilhinney

Comment: Then you did something wrong. Do it right and the problem will go away. The only code you have shown us is the code that moves data from the grid to the `TextBoxes` so how can we possibly comment on anything but that?

Comment: I only added the following for the purpose of filtering the datagridview @jmcilhinney

Comment: In what way is a textbox wrong? Does the column ordinal position change elsewhere and ultimately affect what could be in row.Cells(1) row.Cells(2) etc?

Comment: There are only two reasons that I can think of that you would be saving the wrong data to the wrong columns. Either your insert and/or update commands are messed up or your code to push data back from the `TextBoxes` after editing is wrong. The former is unlikely if you're using a typed `DataSet` but you can certainly check for yourself. The latter is moot if you use data-binding, as you should be.